# Anybody knows the difference between the following options: 1) Build solution, 2) Build [project name], 3) Build only [project name]

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Anybody knows the difference between the following options:

1. Build solution,
2. Build [project name],
3. Build only [project name]
   in visual studio 2019?
   c++

I am using a static variable (static int) inside my program and trying to test different option of build when I convert the variable into non static (int) to check which one opt out linking error, so it is a sort of learning process for myself, but I don't get why there are so many option for build in a single program. This is with respect to the visual studio 2019 which has many option to build a single solution.

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation on these options?

Comment: The only close answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845340/difference-between-build-selection-and-build-solution-in-vs    but the third option is not answered, and also I do not understand the answer there,

Comment: SE isn't the only site with information on this. Microsoft tends to have pretty extensive documentation. Have you done a web search? Have you checked Help?

Comment: They all build the project.  I assume you only have one project in your solution.